# Convert Bit Hash to Hex and then back to Bit Hash

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, hash, bit-manipulation

I'm building a tool that helps find duplicate images. To utilize bktrees, I need to use a bit hash, however, it would be nice to compress that larger bit hash into a smaller hex hash for storage.

The bit hash looks like this:
`dhash_bits = 19965419413067491224447942902196404479`

The hex hash of the bit hash look like this:
`dhash_hex = 0f05332d4d0b471500007722dc7300ff`

I've tried to use `bin(int(dhash_hex,16))` to convert the hex hash back into the bits, but I know this isn't the right way to do it.

**What is the correct way to convert the hex hash back into the bit hash?**

Here is the function that converts the bits into hex:

```
def format_hex(row_hash, col_hash, size=8):
    hex_length = size * size // 4
    return '{0:0{2}x}{1:0{2}x}'.format(row_hash, col_hash, hex_length)
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but doesn't `format(dhash_bits, '032x')`  also produce the `dhash_hex` output?

Comment: At which point, the inverse is just `int(dhash_hex, 16)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yep, you're right, I'm seeing that now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `dhash_bits` is just a *single integer*; the corresponding `dhash_hex` value is also achievable with

```
dhash_hex = format(dhash_bits, '032x')
```

Presumably you used the [`dhash_int()` function](https://github.com/Jetsetter/dhash/blob/master/dhash.py#L108-L117) to obtain it.

The inverse operation then is to just convert the hex back to an integer:

```
dhash_bits = int(dhash_hex, 16)
```

Your `format_hex()` function combines the two numbers for the row and column hashes into a single string; you'd get the two separate numbers again by applying `int()` to each half:

```
row_hash = int(dhash_hex[:len(dhash_hex) // 2], 16)
col_hash = int(dhash_hex[len(dhash_hex) // 2:], 16)
```